# .NET Reporting Tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

Does anyone know a Tutorial for the Reporting in C# .NET. I mean the Reports in "Microsoft.Reporting" Namespace (not Crystal Reports).

Comment: Have you tried Reporting Services:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246.aspx)

Comment: This a very large thema. Can you make your question a little more specific. What do you want to do?

Comment: I will try, but I'm not using MS SQL and therefore there is no MSSQL Server with Reporting-Services

Comment: You may want to take a look at SQL Server Express with Advanced Tools. It comes with the Reporting Services.

Comment: There is an EXCELLENT book you can read all about client side reporting in C#: http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598542

Comment: Its probbly easier to learn client side first as you can put to use your coding skills without having to learn SQL server as you can report on any datasource with client side reports. Once you are familiar with the reporting system transitioning to SQL is much easier.

Comment: You might have a [look here at the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx) on the Namespace, it might get you started.

Comment: It's been a while since this question was asked but I thought I'll share a link for SSRS 2008 R2 tutorial from someone who I know worked hard to create them and hopefully are useful for everyone starting with SSRS [SSRS Tutorial](http://www.katieandemil.com/ssrs-tutorial-for-beginners-2008-r2-step-by-step-pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you probably aren't looking for links that you can find on google yourself, but these cover reporting services in great detail and should cover most of your questions.

1. [Reporting Services Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246.aspx)
2. [Intro to reporting services](http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3495136)
3. [Reporting Services in Action](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/MSReportingServices.aspx)
4. [Webcasts on Reporting Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/gsnowman/archive/2005/10/19/482905.aspx)
5. [Useful reporting services links](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/thepremiers/archive/2008/08/01/useful-reporting-services-links-good-kickstart-with-the-product.aspx)

But I'm pretty sure reporting services is tied pretty close to MS SQL, so if you aren't using it you might have to look for a different solution.

Comment: Client side reporting has absolutely no requirement for MSSQL. All you need is a datasource, an RLDC file and the report viewer control.

Comment: The third one seems to be a good starting point...